# JAXB Not unmarshalling correctly optional Long element (SAXParseException2: For input string: "")

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I've found similar questions but some of the conditions don't apply to my case or the answers do not work.

I created a CXF (3.2.1) SOAP client to consume an external web service so I don't have control over the WSDL and schemas.

The relevant part (not the entire schema) of the service schema is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="LegalEntityService1">
    <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo source="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/metadata/">
    <key xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/metadata/">
    <attribute>LegalEntityId</attribute>
    </key>
    </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityId" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PartyId" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityIdentifier" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element default="1" minOccurs="0" name="GeographyId" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TransactingEntityFlag" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="EffectiveFrom" nillable="true" type="ns0:date-Date"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="EffectiveTo" nillable="true" type="ns0:date-Date"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ObjectVersionNumber" type="xsd:int" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:IntObject"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ActivityCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SubActivityCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TypeOfCompany" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationCodeLe" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationCodeEtb" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationCodeLeValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationCodeEtbValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="JurisdictionName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PlaceOfRegistration" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEmployerFlag" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ParentPsuId" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PsuFlag" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="JurisdictionId" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="GeographyId1" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TerritoryShortName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TerritoryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalAddress" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Name1" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityId1" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
```

I'm specifically having problems with:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityId1" type="xsd:long" sdoXML:dataType="sdoJava:LongObject"/>
```

It is minOccurs=0 so it should allow an empty tag but when it unmarshalles the following response it fails with **javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""**.

The annotation seems correct as it is ***required=false***.

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "LegalEntityId1", namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/legalEntity/legalEntities/legalEntityService/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<Long> legalEntityId1;
```

I don't understand why it is failing. I know the problem is LegalEntityId1 because I checked it with the debugger.

**EDIT #1**
Here is the entire stacktrace https://pastebin.com/jS9Pu4rB.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the type of the element.

`<LegalEntityId1></LegalEntityId1>` this is not a Long format because it is parsed as `""` empty string.
if you need instead a *"null"* meaning, that in xml is *"nil"* you should change your xsd in `<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityId1" type="xsd:long" nillable="true" />` that in xml will be `<LegalEntityId1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>` .

Comment: But that is what minOcurrs="0" means. It allows to send an empty tag.

Comment: @ANY The `minOccurs` indicator specifies the minimum number of times an element can occur.

Comment: An empty tag matches the indicator minOccurs=0. If you validate an XML with an element that is empty and the schema declaration for that element has minOccurs=0 the XML would be valid. As I mentioned in the post I can't alter the schema as is a 3rd party and they won't alter it because it *is valid*. What I'm concerned with is the JAXB representation of that schema.